# Jquery when.apply().done waits for one ajax call, but not another?

Tags: jquery

I have a .each function where each "each" amkes an ajax call. I need to wait for them all to finish before continuing to make yet another ajax call. I'm using the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044468/wait-for-each-to-finish-given-each-has-ajax-calls). The crazy thing is, Once I changed the url of the Ajax call in the end function, it stopped working; the function doesn't wait for all the ajax calls to finish.

```
var iarr=[];

$.getJSON("http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=blablbla-get several-links", {},

function (data) { //links returned through json
var def = [];
$.each(data.results.bindings, function () {
    var tlink = this.link.value;
    def.push(getmeta(tlink)); //get the meta values for each link
});
$.when.apply($, def).done(postmetas());
});
```

The getmeta function looks like this:

```
function getmeta(lnk){
var dfd=$.Deferred();
$.ajax({
       url: "meta.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: {url: lnk},
       dataType: "json",
       async: true,
       success: function (r) {
       if (r !==null){
       iarr.push({
                    "title": r.title,
                    "desc": r.desc,
                    "url": r.url
                     });
                     dfd.resolve();
                }
                }
     });
return dfd.promise();
}
```

Finally, the postmetas function, which should not be called until all the getmeta's are finished:

```
 function postmetas(){
   $.ajax({ //
            url: "meta.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {url: wik},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                iarr.push({
                          "title": r.title,
                          "desc": r.desc,
                          "url": r.url
                          });
         console.log(iarr);
                }
    });

      }
}
```

This works great, and after all the ajax calls have been finished, the log gives me all the values in the iarr array.

Here's the thing: When I changed the postmetas function to the following, the whole thing stopped working, and postmetas gets called before all the "getmeta"s have finished. Can anyone figure out why?

```
function postmetas() {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=blabla-some-text",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (r) {
        var descr = r.results.bindings[0].abstract.value;
        var subtitle = descr.substr(0, descr.indexOf('. '));
        iarr.push({
            "title": wtitle, //wtitle is a variable we established before
            "desc": subtitle,
            "url": wurl  //wurl is a variable we established before
        });
        console.log(iarr);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  async: false in both ajax calls

Comment: What did you mean by "both"? using async:false in getmetas isn't an option, as there are quite a lot of them and the browser would probably totally lock up. Using it in hte second postmetas wouldnt really help, as I'm trying to stop postmetas from being called yet!

Comment: why you are not using type:"POST" in your second postmetas function.

Comment: that was an oversight, but I added it and it didn't make a difference.