# Jquery deferred - done doesn't wait for resolve()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I need to do some async ajax calls and in the end of every single one I push a number to an array when all ajax calls finished I call my callback function with this array. But can't figure out how to do so..

So I've tried to implement the deferred method in my code like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9044635/1577384)

Ended up like this:

```
function uploader(uploads, cb) {
  var def     = [];
  var reslist = [];
  $.each(uploads,function(key,value){
    if(!value.sync){
      def.push(_upload(value));
    }
  });
  function _upload(upload){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    getAntrag(upload.timestamp, function(json) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.***.com/',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          customer: json
        },
        async: false,
        success: function(msg) {
          try {
            var res = JSON.parse(msg);
          } catch (err) {
            dfd.reject();
          }

          if (res.mldgcode === '0000') {
            reslist.push(res.data.ident);
            dfd.resolve();

          } else {
            dfd.reject();
          }

        }
      });
    });
    return dfd.promise();
  }
  $.when.apply($,def).done(function(){
    console.log('all done');
    cb(reslist);
  });
  $.when.apply($,def).fail(function(args){
    console.log('failargs',args);
    cb(args);
  });
}
```

So but now the done handler is called before my `dfd.resolve()`.

What do I miss here ?

Comment: Try `$.when(def).done`

Comment: How do you know when `dfd.resolve()` executes, did you put a log there?

Comment: Why do you use `async:false`???

Comment: @Bergi yes I did, and the async:false doesn't matter in my opinion but I tested it without it - no change

Comment: Hm, this is really odd, looks like it should be working. Can you log the value of `def` right before you call `$.when`?

Comment: @Bergi oh man thank you very much the `async:false` was the problem.. I'm such an idiot I lost overview of my code :D if you post it as answer it would be a pleasure to mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: `getAntrag` is asynchronous, isn't it? I wonder how it made a difference then. And the `done` handler must not be called before `resolve()` when all promises are correctly constructed and passed to `when`.

Comment: Marvin, for a slightly cleaner solution, (a) use `$.map(uploads, ...)`to build `def`, (b) return null if `value.sync` is thuthy, (c) resolve the Deferreds with `dfd.resolve(res.data.ident)` and allow the promises to convey the data rather than build the separate array `relist`, (d) in the done handler, compose what was `relist` with `Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)`. Also take a look at the fail hanlder; I don't think that what you call `args` is plural, ie not the array that `cb()` appears to expect.

Comment: I'll post my suggestions in full if you wish but would need to do so as an answer (which they are not).

Comment: Testing in Opera, `async:false` makes no difference - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ecy1jszz/), but maybe some other browsers don't fire the success handler.