# JQuery load function for group of links one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sleep, jquery-load

I have an `ul` which contains many links. when using jQuery  to load these links, it renders them all at same time. How can i load them one by one,  having attempted the following:

js:

```
$('#publish').click(function() {
    $('#get_links li').
        each(function() {
            $(this).load('test.php',{'post':$(this).text()});
            $(this).html("<i class='icon-spin icon-spinner'></i>Loading");

            ///NEED TOSLEEP UNTILL $.load finish..
        }
        );
     }
);
```

How can i sleep the .each loop until .load finish ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Continue Execution Only After .each() Completes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043968/continue-execution-only-after-each-completes)

Comment: I think the questions are unique enough - the one you cited doesn't have to do with `$().load()` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$().load` callback for this:

```
$('#publish').click(function(){
    var $link = $('#get_links li').first();

    var loadLink = function() {
        $link.load('test.php', { post: $link.text() }, function() {
            // once loading is done, grab the next link...
            $link = $link.next();
            // ... and load it if we found one
            if ($link.length) loadLink();
        }).html('<i class="icon-spin icon-spinner"></i>Loading');
    };

    // load the first link
    loadLink();
});
```

Comment: wow .. never thought of using .next() ! :). thats perfect thanks alot